# Where to get the Pali Canon in Pali?

Tags: pali-canon, pali-language, books, tipitaka, scripture

Does anyone know of a place on the Internet, where one can find the entire Pali Canon written in Pali ? I did a basic search but could not find any such resource.
          Also, where can one buy a hard-copy of the entire Pali Canon(written in Pali) ? It would be helpful even if someone can point me to hard-copies of at least the Sutta-Pitaka in Pali ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a hard copy text of the Pali Text Society edition from:

The Pali Text Society: http://palitext.com
(they also have sets of the translations) Become a member and receive a nice discount.

You can find an on-line version of the BJT text at:
Metta Net Lanka:
http://www.metta.lk/tipitaka/index.html

You can get a searchable CD from the Vipassana Research Institute:
http://www.vridhamma.org/Chattha-Sangayana-CD-ROM-Update

Access to insight
http://accesstoinsight.org
has the pali text linked to the suttas they have posted. This is the BJT text and I believe has the entire Pali, not just the ATI-linked suttas.

I have a different version, linked to the suttas I have posted. It is based on the BJT version, proofed against the PTS version. Incomplete, but formatted in a way that is very readable. Working towards completion. Not likly for a good time yet.
http://obo.genaud.net
see the What's New Page for new listings, the Sutta Index for what is now available.

Answer (score 7):

Also check out [suttacentral.net](https://suttacentral.net/), really good sources in Pali, Chinese, Sanskrit, Tibetan and various different language translations..

Comment: Sutta Central is a marvellous resource which enables one to find the Chinese and other language counterparts to Pāli texts and vice versa. Mainly Chinese, Sanskrit and Gāndhārī, with a very few Tibetan texts that have counterparts in Pāḷi. Chinese texts come with a look-up function to help identify words - and it is a definite improvement on Google translator :-)

Answer (score 3):

- [**Digital Pāli Reader**](https://www.digitalpalireader.online) provides two editions of the Pāli Canon: one from Myanmar and one from Thailand. This is the best Pāli reader that I've come across. It can recognise inflected words and analyse compounds, and it uses some of the best Pāli dictionaries: the Pāli-English Dictionary (PED) from the Pāli Text Society and the Dictionary of Pāli Proper Names (DPPN) by G. P. Malalasekera. The site also contains links to translations of the suttas from [accesstoinsight.org](https://accesstoinsight.org), [dhammatalks.org](https://dhammatalks.org) and [palicanon.org](http://palicanon.org).
- [**SuttaCentral**](https://suttacentral.net) provides Pāli suttas from the Mahāsaṅgīti Tipiṭaka Buddhavasse 2500 edition of the Pāli Canon (from Thailand, which was in turn based on the VRI edition from Myanmar). It looks like the Pāli texts have better formatting and punctuation here than in most other editions. SuttaCentral also has root texts in other canonical languages (Chinese, Sanskrit, Tibetan, etc.), as well as modern translations.
- [**GRETIL** (the Göttingen Register of Electronic Texts in Indian Languages)](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/) has a [section about Pāli](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil.html#Pali), providing the Pāli Canon in the text format (without an online Pāli reader). It also includes paracanonical texts, chronicles, commentaries (Visuddhimagga), etc. There are two editions of the Canon: BJT Sri Lanka Buddha Jayanti Tripiṭaka Series and PTS from the Pāli Text Society. The formatting and punctuation of the PTS edition is not great, but it does have one advantage: proper nouns are capitalised, which makes them easier to recognise.
- [**BJT Sri Lanka Buddha Jayanti Tripiṭaka Series**](http://metta.lk/tipitaka/index.html)
- [**Access to Insight**](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/) has the Pāli Canon from the [SLTP (Sri Lanka Tripiṭaka Project)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sltp/), the same as or very similar to BJT. On this website, the Tipiṭaka is organised according to PTS books and page numbers.